# Flash an image in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Python version: 3.5.1 and PyGame Version: 1.9.2a0

My main goal is to flash an image on the screen. On for 0.5 seconds, off for 0.5 seconds.

I know that the following can work for 60fps

```
frameCount = 0
imageOn = False
while 1:

    frameCount += 1



    if frameCount % 30 == 0:   #every 30 frames
        if imageOn == True:   #if it's on
            imageOn = False   #turn it off
        elif imageOn == False:   #if it's off
            imageOn = True   #turn it on



    clock.tick(60)
```

But I don't think it's practical to be counting the frames in an int. Eventually my frame number will be too large to be stored in an int.

How can I flash an image every x seconds without storing my current frame (in this case frameCount) in an integer? Or is this actually the most practical way to do it?

Comment: Note that python Ints are not limited to 32-bits: they are automatically converted to "bigints". Also note that at 60 fps, your game would need to be running about 2.3 years before needing more than 32bits.

Comment: Interesting point Daan. Also Racialz, you can have an if statement that can reset it if you're worried about it. if frameCount > 1000000: frameCount = 0 Edit: one of the answer addressed what i previously stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid making your game depend on frame rate, as it will change everything depending on what that frame rate is, and if a computer can't run the frame rate, the entire game just slows down.

This variable will help us keep track of how long has passed.
Before while loop:

```
elapsed_time = 0
```

To find time it takes for a frame. my_clock is a pygame Clock object, and 60 is arbitrary

```
elapsed_time += my_clock.tick(60) # 60 fps, time is in milliseconds
```

And you can have an if statement somewhere in your while loop:

```
if elapsed_time > 500 # milliseconds, so .5 seconds
    imageOn = False if imageOn else True
    elapsed_time = 0 # so you can start counting again
```

Edit: I advise looking at Chritical's answer for a simpler way to change the True False value of imageOn. I used an inline conditional, which works, but it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this helps you, but to keep your `frameCount` from growing too large, you could just make it equal to `0` whenever you change the state of `imageOn`, e.g.

```
if frameCount % 30 == 0:
    if imageOn == True:
        imageOn = False
        frameCount = 0
    elif imageOn == False:
        imageOn = True
        frameCount = 0
```

However, I only recommend this as a last resort if no one else answers the question in a better way. Hope this helps, even if a little bit!

EDIT: I just realised, you could also structure your code more neatly by simply making `imageOn = not imageOn`:

```
if frameCount % 30 == 0:
    imageOn = not imageOn
    frameCount = 0
```

Comment: thanks, both of these are helpful, I was wondering if python had some trick like you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You could try using pygame [timers](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def flashImage():
    imageOn = not imageOn

pygame.init()
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 500)  # 500 ms = 0.5 sec
imageOn = False
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == USEREVENT+1:
            flashImage()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            break
```